# Which word would be a good replacement for "office" in this text?

Tags: translation, word-in-context

This is a literal transcription of a text in Portuguese:

> The judge understood that the sergeant could not be found guilty of things that he was obliged to do in the **exercise of his office**.

Is the word "office" used correctly in this context, meaning the job done by a military person, or there is a better or more appropriate word to use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oxford Dictionaries says [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/office) about

> **office**
>   NOUN
>
> **3.1** *dated* A duty attaching to one's position.
>   *the offices of a nurse*

This particular meaning says *dated* but the word **office** is relevant because the sergeant in question is a [non-commissioned officer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-commissioned_officer); an officer but not formally recognised as such.

But the meaning does suggest another word that could be used, and OD has [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/duty) to say about

> **duty**
>   NOUN
>
> **2** (often **duties**) A task or action that one is required to perform as part of one's job.
>   *You will have sentry duty to perform in the evening and duties throughout the day.*

So the sentence you asked about could be

> The judge understood that the sergeant could not be found guilty of things that he was obliged to do in the exercise of his duty.

Comment: That's the word I was looking for... Thanks a lot.